# Cannot add material when inserting from a plugin via InsertModelSDF()

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

When I insert a model in the environment from a plugin with `InsertModelSDF()` and I try to give it a material, I get an error.

The code is something like this:

```
    std::stringstream xml;

    ...
    xml << "\t\t\t<visual name='sphere_visual_" << i << "'>\n";
    xml << "\t\t\t\t<geometry>\n";
    xml << "\t\t\t\t\t<sphere>\n";
    xml << "\t\t\t\t\t\t<radius>" << radius << "</radius>\n";
    xml << "\t\t\t\t\t</sphere>\n";
    xml << "\t\t\t\t</geometry>\n";
    //xml << "\t\t\t\t<material/>\n";
    //xml << "\t\t\t\t\t<script>\n";
    //xml << "\t\t\t\t\t\t<uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>\n";
    //xml << "\t\t\t\t\t\t<name>Gazebo/Red</name>\n";
    //xml << "\t\t\t\t\t</script>\n";
    //xml << "\t\t\t\t</material>\n";
    xml << "\t\t\t</visual>\n";
    ...

    sdf::SDF sphereSDF;
    sphereSDF.SetFromString(xml.str());

    _parent->InsertModelSDF(sphereSDF);
```

If I uncomment the  tag I get an error and the whole model is not loaded.

```
Error [World.cc:1383] Unable to find a model, light, or actor in:
<sdf version='1.3'/>
```

Bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks, Andrei

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1219/cannot-add-material-when-inserting-from-a-plugin-via-insertmodelsdf()./) by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 2108 on 2013-02-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I think your SDF is incorrect. Look at the start of your material XML element. It has an forward slash that shouldn't be there:

```
<material/>
```

should be

```
<material>
```

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-02-05**:
You are right, sorry for not noticing it.